# Computing a rolling quantile

Tags: statistics

An algorithm I'm writing needs to compute rolling quantiles of a time series. Currently I do this in the naive way: for a window of size `W` and a vector `X` of size `N`

```
for t from W to N:
  q[t,:] = quantiles(X[t-W+1:t])
```

However, it seems that there should be a faster way, given that I know the previous quantile `q[t-1]`, the new data `X[t]` and the data `X[t-W]` that has just dropped out of the window. I'm thinking of something along the lines of the well (?) known incremental mean algorithm:

```
for t from W to N:
  m[t] = m[t-1] + ( x[t] - x[t-W] ) / W
```

which avoids recalculating the mean at every stage. Even an approximation would be good. I've seen approximations for computing quantiles on *streams*, but it is important to me that I have a rolling window, not just an expanding window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution would be to keep your rolling window of data sorted using a [self-balancing binary tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree) or a [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table).  On every update, you pay a constant insertion cost, a $O(n)$ deletion cost, and a $O(n)$ traversal cost to update the quintiles.

Comment: +1 for the self-balancing tree. How would you use a hash table to maintain a sort order? And I would think that insertion, deletion, and quantile computation are all $O(\log(n))$? (Note also that [quantiles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile) are more general than [quintiles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintile).)